# How to target same page using RequestID with SOAP APIs

Tags: soap, salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud

How do I target the same page of data using the pagination in case of timeout issue
Reference: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321015/pagination-in-soap/321603#321603